# How do I produce a barchart of one factor conditioned on another factor?

Tags: r, lattice

Given a data frame like the following, with 2 or more factors:

```
 data <- data.frame(V1=sample(c('A','B','C'), 50, T), V2=sample(c('X','Y'),50,T))
```

I can produce a barchart of the tabulation of a factor independently, for example:

```
library(lattice)
with(data, barchart(V1))
```

How can I produce a multi-panel plot conditioned on the value of the second factor? The syntax I would expect to use is:

```
with(data, barchart(V1 | V2))
```

But this produces the following warning:

```
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(V1, V2) : | not meaningful for factors
```

and no meaningful output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call `with(data, barchart(V1))` you are calling `barchart` on an object of class factor and it is calling `barchart.default`, which calls the equivalent of `barchart(table(V1))` (and thus calls `barchart.table`) producing the plot you want.

If you want to have both `V1` and `V2` included you have to use them in your table, ie.

```
with(data, barchart(table(V1, V2))
```

[image]

You can then use `groups = TRUE` to set the last dimension as the grouping variable

eg

```
with(data, barchart(table(V1, V2), groups = TRUE))
```

[image]

If you want to use the formula method, you will have to calculate the values yourself beforehand.

eg

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(data)

 barchart(V1~N|V2,DT[, .N,by= list(V1,V2)])
```

which gives the same result as `with(data, barchart(table(V1, V2), groups = TRUE))`

Comment: On my version of R (R version 2.14.1 (2011-12-22) on Ubuntu 12.04), groups = TRUE has no effect, and both plots look the same. I also don't seem to have a package `data.table`, does it need to be installed separately?

Comment: Did not manage to edit the previous comment in time. `data.table` is a third-party package and can be installed with `install.packages("data.table")`.

Comment: @saffsd -- yes, `data.table` is a package available from `CRAN`. What version of `lattice` are you using. I am using `0.20-15` (and R 3.0.0). Perhaps you should be updating `lattice`. `lattice` version `0.20.10` (the oldest I can test) fails to work as well.

Comment: The lattice version is probably the problem. I have it installed via apt, so I have version `0.20.0`, which is the latest in `precise/universe`. I will look into upgrading R/lattice, thanks.